# How to enable /metrics endpoint on InfluxDB

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, influxdb, metrics

I have a running instance of InfluxDB in my kubernetes cluster.

[According to documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.5/reference/internals/metrics/) I'm supposed being able to monitor my instance scrapping the `/metrics` endpoint with prometheus.

Unfortunately anytimes I'm hitting **GET my-influx:8086/metrics** I got the following error message :

```json
{
 "code":"forbidden",
 "message":"metrics disabled"
}
```

I cannot find anything related to some kind of activation in the doc, neither got a response on their slack server.

Hope to have more chance here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have disabled the metrics endpoint, either by setting `--metrics-disabled` command line flag, environment variable `INFLUXD_METRICS_DISABLED=true` or config value `metrics-disabled: true`?

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.5/reference/config-options/#metrics-disabled

Comment: Thanks! I missed that part of the doc! :)